# Which data structures can be used to implement a pool of integers?

Tags: data-structures, pool

These integers can be IP addresses (DHCP) or session IDs or tunnel IDs (in L2TP for example).
Each integer can be free or used. We need it to be efficient for finding free ones.

There's also a min and max defined.

Comment: This problem is very similar to memory allocation. You might find some answers in that problem domain.

Comment: I see what you mean. If I take malloc, each byte of memory will correspond to one integer in my problem. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (And if you implement "Nobody"s answer you need to tackle problems similar to memory fragmentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as you have a maximum and minimum I have following Idea:
You maintain this maximum or minimum dynamically and have a list of free integers.
At first you start with an empty list and the full range.
When someone leases an integer the range decreases in size by one if the list is empty if not we take from the list.
If he releases his integer there are 2 possibilities:

1. It fits to the edge of your max/min-range so you increase the ranges size
2. It lies far away from the range so you put it into the list

This should give you the possibility to maintain also high and low free integer count with low cost.
Of course you could also try to save several ranges to cluster the integers together but that would need more complicated operations.

Comment: I like this a little. Another idea I had was starting with a range and once the entire range is used, fall back to a list based mechanism. This just minimizes the startup cost.

Comment: For multiple ranges, are these range trees and interval trees that I hear of good? I remember seeing one implementation of IP Address pools where they used some concept of range, but it was definitely not a tree (or was it?)

Comment: sorry but I dont know about those trees. My idea was just some fresh thought and I am sure that there is already some solution to this because DHCP-Servers should be progammed efficiently (at least I hope so) and solve the same problem. Maybe you should take a look there too, as my idea is not that "elaborated"

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect to have more free or more used integers?
And do you want to save IPs, SessIds and TunIds at the same time or each excluding the others?

For me the most balanced would be a tree but as you know about a maximal size an array could be sufficient if there are no frequent changes.

When you dont care for some order then dynamic lists would be best.

Comment: Let's assume that i only have to store one kind of 'id' for simplicity. The various examples I gave are hypothetical. If you're still curious my use case is GTP tunnel ids. I cannot say if we'll have more free or used ids at a given time, but we should be prepared for the worst case, that is all used.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep a free list and a used list. Allocating a number would mean moving it from free list to the used list, and deallocation the reverse.

There would be a cost to maintaining the lists, but *finding* a free number would be fast

Comment: That's what I'm doing currently. But I end up creating 2^24 nodes in the list at launch. So, the memory usage is constant, the worst case, in fact.